# Appending to YAML file

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I can't figure out how to work with YAML files, I have a `db.yaml` file with this content

```
beatport_links:
    afro-house: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/afro-house/89/top-100"
    big-room: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/big-room/79/top-100"
    breaks: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/breaks/9/top-100"
```

My program reads genre name and link to top 100 from this file, then it scraps the web page for song names and adds it to dictionary

```
def load_yaml_file(self):
    with open(self.yaml_file, "r") as file_content:
        self.data = yaml.load(file_content)

def get_genres_and_links(self):
    for genre, link in self.data.get("beatport_links").items():
        self.beatport_links[genre] = link
```

Now I have a list with contents like this

```
["Adam_Beyer_-_Rome_Future_(Original_Mix)", "Veerus_-_Wheel_(Original_Mix)"]
```

I would like my program to update `db.yaml` file with contents from this list (append to it), so in the end I would like `db.yaml` to look like this:

```
beatport_links:
    afro-house: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/afro-house/89/top-100"
    big-room: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/big-room/79/top-100"
    breaks: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/breaks/9/top-100"
downloaded:
    Adam_Beyer_-_Rome_Future_(Original_Mix)
    Veerus_-Wheel(Original_Mix)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You should not be using PyYAML's `load()` that way, it is documented to be potentially unsafe. Use `safe_load()` if you have to use PyYAML. There is also something missing as  `self` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your `get_genres_and_links` you can directly update your `self.data`
by doing:

```
self.data['downloaded'] = some_data
```

The problem is that in your expected output you have as value for the key `downloaded` you have a multiline plain scalar and not a list. Although you can do `some_data = ' '.join(["Adam_Beyer_-_Rome_Future_(Original_Mix)", "Veerus_-_Wheel_(Original_Mix)"])` will get you the string value, it is almost impossible to get the PyYAML to output the plain scalar multiline and non-compact (reading that is trivial. Instead I would look at dumping to a literal block style scalar and joining the list using `"\n".join()`. The output would then look like:

```
beatport_links:
    afro-house: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/afro-house/89/top-100"
    big-room: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/big-room/79/top-100"
    breaks: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/breaks/9/top-100"
downloaded: |-
    Adam_Beyer_-_Rome_Future_(Original_Mix)
    Veerus_-Wheel(Original_Mix)
```

(you can get rid of the dash after `|` by appending a newline after the joining the list items).

---

If your expected output was acceptable looking like:

```
beatport_links:
    afro-house: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/afro-house/89/top-100"
    big-room: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/big-room/79/top-100"
    breaks: "https://www.beatport.com/genre/breaks/9/top-100"
downloaded:
    - Adam_Beyer_-_Rome_Future_(Original_Mix)
    - Veerus_-Wheel(Original_Mix)
```

then things are easier and doing:

```
self.data['downloaded'] = ["Adam_Beyer_-_Rome_Future_(Original_Mix)", "Veerus_-_Wheel_(Original_Mix)"]
with open('some_file', 'w') as fp:
    yaml.safe_dump(self.data, fp)
```

would be enough.

---

In any event, if you do this kind of loading, modifying, dumping, then you 
should look seriously at `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). Not only does it implement the newer YAML 1.2, it also preserves comments, tags, special ids, key-order when doing this kind of round-tripping. It also has built-in support for literal style block scalars. And apart from that its default `.load()` is safe.

Comment: Thank you, i can't get it to work anyway, it's a bit too complicated so i think im gonna just use plain text file instead.